# How to setup multiple WANs with load balancing?

Tags: server, internet, routing

What is the best way to setup multiple WAN's into a Ubuntu distro and load balance?
I have two internet connections, one static and one dynamic and I need to combine and load balance them. I have been looking into the following method http://www.netlife.co.za/archived-articles/12-started.html but was wondering if anyone had suggestions that were more Ubuntu specific or possibly other distro's that would work better for this.

Comment: A GUI tool would be awesome for the lazy amoung us, but I suspect this will be a heavily hackish solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Zentyal, previously known as eBox, offers that functionality, and it's easily installable on Ubuntu.

Version 1.4 is available from the repositories as eBox, and version 2.0 can be installed from an additional repository.

See here: http://www.zentyal.org/
And here is a nice detailed HOWTO: http://www.howtoforge.com/using-ebox-as-a-gateway-firewall-traffic-shaping-http-proxy-and-more

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is that while you can create configurations to load balance your *outbound* traffic, you won't be able to control your *inbound* traffic. The inbound traffic is aimed at a specific IP address, and each of your Internet connections has a separate IP, as assigned by the upstream provider. Doing this requires coordination with your upstream provider, and likely a full [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) configuration to publish alternate routes, etc. Doing bonding (combining traffic) would also need the upstream involved.

Comment: isn't a reverse proxy the right solution for load balancing inbound traffic?

Answer (score -1):

Try out Zeroshell, bundled with an Linux.

Runs very smooth on low end h/w with no glitches.

Configuration options lets to play as you want.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Zeroshell is at EOL. However, the latest version is still downloadable as on date.